# Network interface is down then is up with different speed

Tags: linux, centos, linux-networking, bonding, lag

i have a HP ProLiant server with 4 physical network ports. `eth0` and `eth1` are bonded together. today we faced a lag in our services, turned out that `eth0` was down then up with 1000Mbps speed then went down again and up with 100Mbps speed.
why interface is up with different speed? what is the reason and is it possible to prevent it from happening again?

---

here is the Bonding configuration:

```
DEVICE=Bond0
IPADDR=x.x.x.x
NETMASK=x.x.x.x
GATEWAY=x.x.x.x
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
USERCTL=no

DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=XXXXX
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=XXXXXXX
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
USERCTL=no
MASTER=Bond0
SLAVE=yes

DEVICE=eth1
HWADDR=XXXXX
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=XXXXXXX
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
MASTER=Bond0
SLAVE=yes
```

and bonding status:

```
Bonding Mode: load balancing (round-robin)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 0
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

Slave Interface: eth0
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: XXXXXXX
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: eth1
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: XXXXXXXX
Slave queue ID: 0
```

messages in log:

```
Dec 16 11:00:33 Adata kernel: tg3 0000:02:00.0: eth0: Link is down
Dec 16 11:00:36 Adata kernel: tg3 0000:02:00.0: eth0: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
Dec 16 11:00:36 Adata kernel: tg3 0000:02:00.0: eth0: Flow control is off for TX and off for RX
Dec 16 11:00:36 Adata kernel: tg3 0000:02:00.0: eth0: EEE is disabled
Dec 16 11:00:44 Adata kernel: tg3 0000:02:00.0: eth0: Link is down
Dec 16 11:01:01 Adata kernel: tg3 0000:02:00.0: eth0: Link is up at 100 Mbps, full duplex
Dec 16 11:01:01 Adata kernel: tg3 0000:02:00.0: eth0: Flow control is off for TX and off for RX
Dec 16 11:01:01 Adata kernel: tg3 0000:02:00.0: eth0: EEE is disabled
```

Comment: It sounds like it has trouble negotiating 1000 Mbps speed or doesn't think it's reliable at that speed and so negotiates the lower speed. Is there a way to force it as 1000 and check for dropped packets / errors?

Comment: @Smock let me try